# How to count how many lines in a file are the same?

Tags: python, file, count, comparison

I have a text document in the format of:

```
-1+1
-1-1
+1+1
-1-1
+1-1
...
```

I want to have a program that counts how many lines have -1+1 lines and +1-1 lines. The program would then just need to return the value of how many lines are like this.

I have written the code:

```
f1 = open("results.txt", "r")
fileOne = f1.readlines()
f1.close()

x = 0
for i in fileOne:
    if i == '-1+1':
        x += 1
    elif i == '+1-1':
        x += 1
    else:
        continue

print x
```

But for some reason, it always returns 0 and I have no idea why.

Comment: Before anything else, why read the file into memory, then iterate over it? Just iterate over the file. (And use the `with` statement when dealing with files!)

Comment: Without Python, `sort results.txt | uniq -c` tells you which lines and how often appear in the file.

Comment: In the future you might also want to try `'+1-1' in i`. Which will check if the string occurs in `i` not just if the values are equal.

Comment: @eumiro Cheers for that piece of code. So much easier that way!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead:

```
import collections

with open('results.txt') as infile:
    counts = collections.Counter(l.strip() for l in infile)
for line, count in counts.most_common():
    print line, count
```

Most of all, remove whitespace (the newline specifically, but any other spaces or tabs might interfere too) when counting your lines.

Comment: Lucky Luke wins again. (for python2.7 or newer)

Comment: Naturally, if the asker wants two different rows, it's as simple as `counts['-1+1'] + counts['+1-1']`.

Comment: How does it know that which lines aren't the same values (-1+1 or +1-1) ?

Comment: @mrpopo As I say in the comment above, it doesn't, but you can sum the individual counts to get the group one. If you have more values you want to group, you could use something like: `sum(counts[x] for x in ('-1+1', '+1-1', ...)`

Comment: @mrpopo: It doesn't know that those two are supposed to be counted together, no. You can sum the two counts easily enough though, or you can try and 'normalize' the lines in the generator expression inside the `Counter()` call. Keeping it simple would be best though.

Comment: When I run it, for some reason I get 'collections is not defined'. Is this because I need to keep the f1 = open("results.txt", "r")
fileOne = f1.readlines() at the top of the code but rename fileOne to collections?

Comment: @mrpopo: No, you don't need to keep that; you need to `import collections` though (sorry, I've made that explicit in my answer now).

Comment: Thanks for all your help. However, I'm still a bit confused. I'm not too sure where I have to tell it which lines to count. Please be patient as I am fairly new to python!

Comment: @mrpopo: It'll count *all* lines; you have to loop over the whole file anyway, so that doesn't matter really. Just take the counts you care about and ignore the rest. A `Counter()` is basically a `dict` object, so you can ask it for specific counts, like `counts['+1-1']` and `counts['-1+1']`.

Comment: For your input text, I get `Counter({'-1-1': 2, '+1-1': 1, '+1+1': 1, '-1+1': 1})` (so 2 `'-1-1'` entries, and 1 each of `'+1-1'`, `'+1+1'`, and `'-1+1'`) which would be correct. I think you missed something, but I cannot, from here, tell you what.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just realised what the problem was!!

Answer (score 8):

The `.readlines()` leaves the `\n` in the lines, that's why they don't match.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import a module, enjoy short code, and like a bit of 'list' comprehension :

```
with open('results.txt') as infile:
    counts = { key: infile.count(key) for key in ['-1+1', '+1-1'] }
```

Then of course access `counts` as a dict